# Using @font-face to implement custom fonts multiple times in web page

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using @font-face to  use custom fonts like this

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Simpletext';
  src: url('MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'); 
}
```

now when i want to use  this i am doing like this

```
<p style="font-family:Simpletext ;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<span style="font-family:Simpletext ;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
```

Now instead of repeating this will someone  guide me how can i  define it  just like a class rule and  reuse it like this

```
 <p class="Simpletext"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is regular CSS. Please check a tutorial or similar. This does not apply to `@font-face`

```
<style>
    .your-class {
        font-family:"Simpletext";
    }
</style>
<p class="your-class">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<span class="your-class">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
```

Comment: and if there is already a class implemneted like this               <ul class="nav" > so how can i implement second class so same nav ?

Comment: @Sikander, that’s a different question and should be asked separately, with due facts disclosed, if it is really a problem. You don’t “implement” classes, you just write CSS rules that refer to classes. There is no obvious reason why rules for one class would affect rules for another class, so you would have to explain what the problem really is.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  i am using bootstrap and  used <ul class="nav" > now when i want to apply  custom bold  font class to same  ul how will  i do it thats the problem . i  did not  know how to do that wnhen julian told me now i have to implement it in ul that is already imolementing nav class

Comment: @Sikander, as I wrote, that’s a different problem, but it seems to be a rather trivial one: just use `<ul class="nav your-class">`.

Comment: Or write CSS code like `.nav { font-family:"Simpletext"; }` !!